# Duplicate queries out of the box?

Tags: database, craft4, queries

I'm trying to strip back duplicated queries on a site, but after removing as much as possible from the homepage so nothing is coming from the CMS I'm still getting 7 duplicate queries.

Is it possible that out of the box Craft has a small amount of duplicate queries just to run?

Comment: Found another similar post and their issue was SEOMatic causing duplicates, which we also have installed.

Comment: Disabling the SEOMatic plugin removes all duplicate queries that were left.

Comment: Can you add that as a proper answer, and then accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the SEOMatic plugin removes all duplicate queries that were left (there were 7)